# Changing link color of sub menus being visited on a one-page website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help again, I have a one-page website with a navbar, which has sub menus. There is some javascript code that changes color of links that are currently being visited, which I'll provide below. Now, this works fine, but I really can't figure out how to make it work for the 'services' link, which holds the sub menu. No matter what I try it just won't change the color of that one link.

Here's what I'd like to do:
If I click on any of the sub menus, it changes that link color to blue, and also the 'services' link, which is the one that holds all the sub menu links.
On scroll to other ID's, makes it go back to white, both the 'service' and whatever was selected within it.

I already figured out how to make it work for the main class, but not for the sub menus...

Can someone please help?

Thank you!!

```js
(() => {
    // Active links
    $('.header .menu > .menu-item > a').click(function() {
      $('.header .menu > .menu-item > a.activenavlink').removeClass('activenavlink');
      $(this).addClass('activenavlink');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var href = $(this).scrollTop();
      $('.header .menu > .menu-item > a').each(function(event) {
        if (href >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 1) {
          $('.header .menu > .menu-item > a.activenavlink').removeClass('activenavlink');
          $(this).addClass('activenavlink');
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
/*header*/

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.header-main {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 8vh;
  opacity: .9;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #88ff00, #006aff) 1;
}

.header .logo {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.header .nav-menu {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


/************************SUB MENUS********************************/

.header .menu>.menu-item>a .plus {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>a .plus:before,
.header .menu>.menu-item>a .plus:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item:hover>a .plus:before,
.header .menu>.menu-item:hover>a .plus:after {
  background-color: #88ff00;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>a .plus:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>.sub-menu {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
  width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .8;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #88ff00;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .header .menu>.menu-item-has-children:hover>.sub-menu {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .header .menu>.menu-item-has-children:hover>a .plus:after {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>.sub-menu>.menu-item {
  display: block;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>.sub-menu>.menu-item>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}


/************************LINK STATES********************************/

.header .menu>.menu-item>.sub-menu>.menu-item>a:hover,
.header .menu>.menu-item:hover>a {
  color: #88ff00;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>.sub-menu>.menu-item>a:active,
.header .menu>.menu-item>a:active {
  color: #006aff;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>a.activenavlink {
  color: #006aff;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-main">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="open-nav-menu">
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-overlay">
      </div>
      <!-- navigation menu start -->
      <nav class="nav-menu">
        <div class="close-nav-menu">
          <img src="images/close.svg" alt="close">
        </div>

        <ul class="menu">

          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#About"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i> About</a>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
            <a href="#services" data-toggle="sub-menu"><i class="fa fa-file-code"></i> Services<i
                           class="plus"></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#service1">Service1</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#service2">Service2</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#service3">Service3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#prices"><i class="fas fa-money-check-alt"></i> Prices</a>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#portfolio"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> Portfolio</a>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#contacts"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contacts</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited ..?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but it doesn't really work for some reason. The only way I could make it work was through JavaScript, however the sub-menu doesn't change the color and I am not really sure how to fix that.

Comment: It works, but you've check the specificity of your CSS rules, a tag selector has a higher specificity than a class selector.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction please? I really don't understand how to make this work